# Calling API from R to retrieve data

Tags: r, api, curl

I am trying to fetch information from the API. I have the Curl statement but unfortunately Curl converter its now not support for R. 
My Curl statement is :

```
   curl -X GET "http://192.168.26.71:8080/recommender/containing/?
   lat=5.010880470275879&lon=47.293949127197266&floor=0" -H "accept: 
   application/json"
```

I am trying with below mentioned code;

```
 library(RCurl)
 library(RJSONIO)
 postForm("http://192.168.26.71:8080/recommender/containing/",
 .opts = list(postfields = toJSON(list('lat' = "5.010880470275879", 
 'lon' = "47.293949127197266", 'floor' = "0" )),
 httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json', Accept = 
 'application/json'),
 ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
```

But its giving me an error as ;

```
 Error: Not Found
 *   Trying 192.168.26.71...
 * Connected to 192.168.26.71 (192.168.26.71) port 8080 (#0)
 > POST /recommender/containing/ HTTP/1.1
 Host: 192.168.26.71:8080
 Content-Type: application/json
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Length: 75

 * upload completely sent off: 75 out of 75 bytes
 < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 < Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 14:24:14 GMT
 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 < Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Location, Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, 
 Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With
 < Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location, Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, 
 Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With
 < Content-Type: application/json
 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 < Server: Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)
 < 
 * Connection #0 to host 192.168.26.71 left intact
  Error: Not Found
```

Can anyone please help me in this ? Thank you :)

Comment: "not found"? enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE, and post the verbose log

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is no CURLOPT_VERBOSE option in R i guess.

Comment: RCurl is a wrapper around the libcurl library, right? would be a shitty wrapper if it didn't have a way for you to enable libcurl's CURLOPT_VERBOSE... where are the RCurl docs?

Comment: guessing by the docs, its done with ```curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt( .opts = list(verbose = TRUE),
curl = curl)```

Comment: Here you go; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf    I have enabled it but still no log it displaying in its output.

Comment: or just add `verbose=TRUE`  to your .opts list*

Comment: most likely it means you're only viewing the STDOUT or GUI, and ignoring the STDERR, by default, the verbose info is written to STDERR. are you reading the programs STDERR?

Comment: Thank you it worked, I was putting it on the wrong location. I have updated my question.

Comment: should update your code too, but now i'm borderline nitpicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your command line request issues a GET and yet your Rcurl code calls `postForm` which is a POST request. Those are never going to be the same. A more similar call would be

```
my_url <- "http://192.168.26.71:8080/recommender/containing/?lat=5.010880470275879&lon=47.293949127197266&floor=0"
getURL(my_url,
   httpheader = c(Accept = 'application/json'),
   ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

The `RCurl` pacakge doesn't really seem to help with building the URL. The `urltools::param_set()` function might help with that. Though the more popular pacakge for making http requests now is `httr`. Your request would look like this

```
library(httr)
GET("http://192.168.26.71:8080/recommender/containing/", 
  query = list('lat' = "5.010880470275879", 
    'lon' = "47.293949127197266", 
    'floor' = "0" ),
  add_headers(Accept = "application/json"))
```